# Why Speed of execution depends on the libc used?

Tags: gcc, linker, riscv, libc

When I link my executable to a libc built by myself with Crosstool-NG, the execution of my program is incomparably slower than if I link my executable with a libc built by a company called Nucleisys and provided by the Platformio project .
Visually, it does not deceive. About 2m30 against more than 10m with mine. (to resolve/stabilize a Conway game of life)

Practically, when I proceed like this :

```
mv ~/x-tools/riscv32-unknown-elf/riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/rv32imac/ ~/x-tools/riscv32-unknown-elf/riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/original_rv32imac
```

If I recompile, obviously the compilation fails:

```
error : /home/th/x-tools/riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/9.4.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-atexit.o): can't link double-float modules with soft-float modules
...
```

Then I deploy the Nuclei lib:

```
cp -a ~/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gd32v/riscv-nuclei-elf/lib/rv32imac ~/x-tools/riscv32-unknown-elf/riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/
```

I don't do anything other than that. I don't touch my makefile.Then, I recompile and only see the speed of execution.
What am I missing?

Both libc seems to be identicals, they are soft-float ABI.

PS : I am in a baremetal environment, I compile with -march=rv32imac -mabi=ilp32

EDIT 1:
Below, the mains switches set by crosstool-NG to compile my libc (newlib) :

```
'--disable-newlib-io-float'
'--disable-newlib-io-long-double'
'--enable-newlib-supplied-syscalls'
'--disable-newlib-io-pos-args'
'--disable-newlib-io-c99-formats'
'--disable-newlib-io-long-long'
'--disable-newlib-register-fini'
'--enable-newlib-nano-malloc'
'--enable-newlib-nano-formatted-io'
'--enable-newlib-atexit-dynamic-alloc' 
'--disable-newlib-global-atexit'
'--disable-lite-exit'
'--disable-newlib-reent-small'
'--enable-newlib-multithread'
'--disable-newlib-retargetable-locking' 
'--enable-newlib-wide-orient' 
'--enable-newlib-fseek-optimization'
'--enable-newlib-fvwrite-in-streamio'
'--enable-newlib-unbuf-stream-opt'
'--enable-target-optspace'
```

EDIT 2:
[A link to the two version of ELF files. The fast and the slow](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HQPBIkCCyxY31mWxPcTX8l7yivC1D8Dr?usp=sharing)

EDIT 3: A comparison between readelf outputs of the two versions of executable. We can see in the fast version, an header that I don't have in the slow : init_array. Maybe a clue...

[image: The elf comparison]

EDIT 4:

If I'm not mistaken, the SP register is initialized in the _start function :

```
la sp, _sp
```

_sp being defined in the linker .script:

```
ram (wxa!ri) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 32K 
__stack_size = DEFINED(__stack_size) ? __stack_size : 2K;
 [....] 
. = ALIGN(8); PROVIDE( _end = . ); /*0X2000,0340*/ 
PROVIDE( end = . );
.stack ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram) - __stack_size : { 
  PROVIDE( _heap_end = . ); . = __stack_size; 
  PROVIDE( _sp = . ); 
} >ram AT>ram
```

In both case, GDB (info registers) tells me : (sp)0x20008000. I'll check again.

EDIT 5: Just redoing the linking+objcopy is enough to see the problem. (or the other way round, the correct fix of the problem). Recompile is unnecessary.

EDIT 6: A very serious lead: The memcpy implementations are drastically different between the two libc versions :(

[image]

EDIT 7: No luck about EDIT 6. Replace the memcpy use in the main loop by a local implementation doesn't fix anything. Still slow with my libc, fast with the other. This is driving me crazy :(

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help without more details, like what functions in libc does the program use — as posted there no basis for comparison other than the performance.

Comment: Does your environment emulate misaligned accesses?  If there's some reason that your libc uses them (for example, a version of `malloc` that doesn't align or `__start` that doesn't align the stack pointer), that might cause serious performance problems.

Comment: The executed program is a Conway game of life. What is annoying is that in fact, once in the game loop, there doesn't seem to be any access to the C library. The display part only seems to be read/write integer at certain addresses (i2s via gpio).

Comment: Does it use the stack memory or any `malloc`'d memory in the game loop?

Comment: Only the stack. The main loop (function void draw_conway_life()) is in available here :
https://github.com/marijnfs/RISC-V-Longan-Nano-Examples/blob/master/gd32v_lcd/src/main.c

Comment: Ok, is the stack properly initialized and properly aligned in both configuration (slow & fast)?

Comment: Is my last screenshot (kdiff) answering your question ?

Comment: Well, this is probably nothing, but I'm more interested in the value in the stack pointer register, which is a dynamic thing typically set up by `__start`.  It should be at least 8 byte aligned when the first instruction of main is encountered, and, it should be pointing within the proper area of the stack segment.  Do you have a way to compare this register value upon entry to `main` with slow vs. fast configuration?

Comment: No problem. All avenues are good to be exploited. I complete my question with EDIT 4.

Comment: aargh, I said something stupid. In the main loop, there is a call to memcpy ! Line 172 of :

https://github.com/marijnfs/RISC-V-Longan-Nano-Examples/blob/master/gd32v_lcd/src/main.c

Answer (score 0):

My libc (newlib) was not compiled with the `_HAVE_INIT_FINI` option:

```
void __libc_init_array (void) {
// ...
#ifdef _HAVE_INIT_FINI
  _init ();
#endif
```

`_init()` is an external function to the libc, which must be defined in its project.
In my project `_init()` if called, sets the frequency of the mcu. In my case, it was not called.